# Finding radius of circle inscribed in trapezium

Tags: geometry

A circle is inscribed in trapezoid $ABCD$. Let $K,L,M,N$ be the points of intersection of the circle with diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ respectively. $K$ is between $A$ and $L$ and $M$ is between $B$ and $N$. Given that $AK*LC = 16$ and $BM*ND = \frac{9}{4}$, find the radius of the circle

I was able to deduce a few elementary things

$AB + CD = AD + BC$ and also tried using power of point and use the given products but didnt get anything useful

Comment: Point E? Where is it?

Comment: sorry it was a typo, its actually B

Comment: Are you sure that the trapezoid is not an isosceles?

Comment: @Lanet $AK\times LC$ would be equal to $BM\times ND$ if the trapezoid was isosceles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When all else fails, get a bigger hammer*

...which I did and found that the answer was $R=6$.

[image]

I won't explain why $AC$, $BD$ $PR$ and $QS$ concur at $F$. It's just a special case of 
[Brianchon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon%27s_theorem). So let's start from there. Notice the angles $\angle CAB=\angle ACD=\alpha$, $\angle ABD=\angle BDC=\beta$ and segment $OF=x$. We'll use them all the time. For the sake of simplicity I will also introduce the following symbols: $AK=p_1$, $LC=p_2$, $BM=q_1$, $DN=q_2$. We know that $p_1p_2=16$ and $q_1q_2=9/4$.

First, let's try to find $p_1=AK$. The same approach will be used to find segments $p_2,q_1,q_2$

Take a look at quadrilateral $AQOK$:

$$AQ=FQ\cot\alpha=AK\cos \alpha+OK\sin\varphi$$

$$QO=AK\sin\alpha+OK\cos\varphi$$

This leads to the following equations:

$$p_1\cos\alpha+R\sin\varphi=(R+x)\cot\alpha$$
$$p_1\sin\alpha+R\cos\varphi=R$$

or:

$$R\sin\varphi=(R+x)\cot\alpha-p_1\cos\alpha$$
$$R\cos\varphi=R-p_1\sin\alpha$$

Square these two equations and add them. This will eliminate the angle $\varphi$ that we don't care about. You will end up with a quadratic equation with respect to $p_1$:

$$R^2=((R+x)\cot\alpha-p_1\cos\alpha)^2+(R-p_1\sin\alpha)^2$$

This equation has two solutions. The bigger one is actually equal to $AL$ and the smaller one is $AK=p_1$:

$$p_1=-\sqrt{R^2-\frac{1}{2} x^2 (1+\cos (2 \alpha))}+(R+x)\cos \alpha \cot \alpha +R \sin \alpha\tag{1}$$

There is no need to calculate $p_2$ in a similar way. Everything would look the same, except that we would use $R-x$ instead of $R+x$ along the way. So we can obtain an expression for $p_2$ just by replacing $x$ with $-x$:

$$p_2=-\sqrt{R^2-\frac{1}{2} x^2 (1+\cos (2 \alpha))}+(R-x)\cos \alpha \cot \alpha +R \sin \alpha\tag{2}$$

Now comes the hardest part: you have to multiply (1) and (2). It looks like we are going nowhere... After a lot of simplifications, we get:

$$p_1p_2=-\frac{1}{2} \csc ^2\alpha \left(\left(R^2+x^2\right)\cos (2 \alpha) +2 R \sin \alpha \sqrt{4 R^2-2 x^2 (1+\cos (2 \alpha))}-3 R^2+x^2\right)\tag{3}$$

At least we know it's 16 :)

The good thing is that we don't have to go through the same torture to find $q_1q_2$, the process is exactly the same except that we have $\beta$ instead of $\alpha$:

$$q_1q_2=-\frac{1}{2} \csc ^2\beta \left(\left(R^2+x^2\right)\cos (2 \beta) +2 R \sin \beta \sqrt{4 R^2-2 x^2 (1+\cos (2 \beta))}-3 R^2+x^2\right)\tag{4}$$

Like it's not difficult enough we have to introduce the fact that $x$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not independent! There's a connection between them.

Take a look at triangle $\triangle ABC$:

$$AB=AQ+QB=(R+x)(\cot\alpha+\cot\beta)$$

$$BC=BR+RC=BQ+CS=(R+x)\cot\beta+(R-x)\cot\alpha$$

$$AC={2R \over \sin\alpha}$$

If you replace all that into a well-known equation:

$$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2 AB\cdot AC\cos\alpha$$

...you will get a very simple relation (trust me):

$$x^2=R^2(1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta)\tag{5}$$

Now replace (5) into (3) and (4) and we'll get something that we can easily deal with:

$$p_1p_2=R^2\left(2+\frac{\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha}-2\sqrt{1+\frac{\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha}}\right)$$

$$q_1q_2=R^2\left(2+\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta}-2\sqrt{1+\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta}}\right)$$

...or, if we introduce $z=\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta}$:

$$p_1p_2=R^2(2+z-2\sqrt{1+z})=R^2(\sqrt{1+z}-1)^2=16\tag{6}$$

$$q_1q_2=R^2\left(2+\frac1z-2\sqrt{1+\frac1z}\right)=R^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1z}-1\right)^2=\frac{9}{4}\tag{7}$$

Now divide (6) by (7) and you get:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+z}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1z}-1}\right)^2=\frac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2}=\frac{16}{\frac94}=\frac{64}{9}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+z}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1z}-1}=\frac{8}{3}$$

$$3(\sqrt{1+z}-1)=8\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1z}-1\right)\tag{8}$$

You should be able to show that equation (8) has only one solution:

$$z=\frac{16}9$$

Replace that into (6) and you get:

$$R^2=\frac{p_1p_2}{(\sqrt{1+z}-1)^2}=36\implies R=6$$

Comment: Why on earth people downvote without a comment - I just cannot understand. This is not the most beautiful solution, but it's correct and the only one that we have so far. I would like to ask the downvoter to provide a better one and I'll delete my answer immediately.